# Countable union of open balls in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Is it possible for any open set $U \in \mathbb{R^n}$ to be written as countable union of open balls? For example this is true when $n=1$. I would like to know if there is similar result in higher dimensions. Thanks

Comment: In $\mathbb R$ it is even possible for any open set to be written as countable union of **disjoint** open intervals. I don't know what happens in higher dimensions, though ...

Comment: @Stefan: Even in the plane you can’t necessarily do it with disjoint open Euclidean balls: you can’t get $(0,1)^2$, for instance, because of the corners.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Isn't it primarily because such a union would not be connected. I didn't think about connectedness earlier ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: That’s a large part of it, but not the whole story: after all, there **are** non-connected open sets in the plane!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, I see, that is exactly what you mean because you only use one single ball for each connected component ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because for each $n$ the space $\Bbb R^n$ has a countable base for the topology consisting entirely of open balls. For example, the open balls of rational radius whose centres are in $\Bbb Q^n$ are such a base.

Comment: They might cover the set. But can we find open balls whose union is exactly the given open set?

Comment: @chandu1729: Yes, of course: that’s an immediate consequence of the fact that they’re a **base** for the topology.